# Understanding non-standard evaluation NSE and standard evaluation SE in dplyr select()

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, dplyr

Would someone be kind enough to explain the differences in the following non-standard evaluation and standard evaluation concepts? Specifically, why some of the methods work and others do not.

I am hopeful that this will serve as a signpost for others (and save them time) and augmentation of the documentation/vignettes. Further, while I believe I have a pretty good grasp as to the explanation, I am certain someone should be able to answer this more elegantly and completely than what I would produce/explain.

```
library(dplyr)
myCols <- c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")

#######################################################################
# Non-Standard Evaluation (NSE)
#######################################################################

# METHOD 1: Works as expected
select(iris, Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)

# METHOD 2: Throws error - must reolve to integer column positions.
select(iris, myCols)

# METHOD 3: Works as expected
select(iris, one_of(myCols))

#######################################################################
# Standard Evaluation (SE)
#######################################################################

# METHOD 4: Returns just Sepal.Width NOT Sepal.Length
select_(iris, myCols)

# METHOD 5: Throws error - must reolve to integer column positions.
select_(iris, ~myCols)

# METHOD 6: Works as expected
select_(iris, .dots = myCols)
```

Comment: Could you expand on what specifically you are missing from the existing vignettes, in particular [the vignette on NSE](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph For starters, how about the **why** behind `METHOD 5` throwing an error vs. `METHOD 6`.

Comment: Why don’t you have a look at what the result of `~myCols` is? You seem to assume that it’s something which it’s not, because the documentation of `select` is quite clear on what parameters `select_` expects.

Comment: More methods that work include e.g `select_(iris, ~match(names(iris), myCols, nomatch=0))` or `select_(iris, gsub('\"', '', deparse(myCols)))`.

Comment: @shadow I can’t tell whether your comment is serious or not.

Comment: This is very late, but you can better understand NSE and SE if you first understand how scoping is done in R: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping and then you should read about environments, then the chapter about NSE.

Comment: SE: standard evaluation; you follow traditional scoping rules (the rules for identifying/locating objects and functions within specific environments). NSE: non-standard evaluation; you break traditional scoping rules (you specify locating stuff). I am **assuming** the NSE version of select sets the environment to `iris` and looks for those specified columns within that environment (and not the global environment).  If you try NSE version of `my_cols`, because that column `my_cols` isn't defined within `iris`, but rather, the global environment, you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still comes across this, I just wanted to note that select_ is now deprecated and methods 1, 2, 3 now all work (produce the two "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length" columns).

And if you have lists of symbols instead of character names for the columns, you can unquote them with !!! and !!. The following is straight from the help file for select().

```
# Unquoting ----------------------------------------

# Like all dplyr verbs, select() supports unquoting of symbols:
vars <- list(
  var1 = sym("cyl"),
  var2 = sym("am")
)
select(mtcars, !!!vars)

# For convenience it also supports strings and character
# vectors. This is unlike other verbs where strings would be
# ambiguous.
vars <- c(var1 = "cyl", var2 ="am")
select(mtcars, !!vars)
rename(mtcars, !!vars)
```